# GCP to AWS Hosted Zone migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, gcloud, google-cloud-dns

I have a publicly hosted zone in GCP for example.com. I want to move the hosted zone to AWS route 53. Is there a tool which can make this process easier?

Alternate:
I will export the records using gcp cloud cli, modify the file to match the AWS route 53 specs, remove NS and SOA records and then import into Amazon route 53 using AWS cli tool

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a tool that does everything (export from GCP and import to AWS). I use your alternate method.

Tip: Be careful and do not import all records such as the SOA. Also, modify the NS records to the new name servers.

You will also need to modify the name server records at your Registrar.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, found a tool called CLI53. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the CLI53 tool

https://github.com/barnybug/cli53

I exported the records from gcp in bind format and imported it using CLI53

Export

```
gcloud dns record-sets export pathtobindfile --zone=<zonename>  --zone-file-format
```

Import

```
cli53 import --file pathtobindfile example.com
```

CLI53 import excludes SOA and NS records by default. It also has a dry run option to see the records being imported

Comment: My answer clearly says CLI53 tool excludes SOA and NS records. And when you create a Route53 zone it creates NS and SOA records.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use any CLI for importing on AWS side.

Process was:

1. Export via GCP cli

   - `gcloud dns record-sets export example.com.format_bind --zone="example-zone" --zone-file-format`
2. Import via AWS Web Console

   - AWS -> Route 53 -> Hosted zones -> Create a new public zone
     "example.com"
3. Click Import zone file, copy-paste the BIND formatted file.

   - Disclaimer on AWS: *When you import a zone file, Route 53 ignores the SOA record in the file. Route 53 also ignores any NS records that have the same name as the hosted zone.*
4. The domain is registered in GoDaddy, so the name servers were changed in there to point AWS.